# Partitions in Datomic mem or free do not work?

Tags: datomic

I'm trying to create a partition in Datomic (free or mem), but, when queried, the new partition does not appear and there is an exception when trying to use it. Is that behavior inherent to free or mem modes?

```
(defn create-mdb []
  (def uri "datomic:mem://localhost:4334//billing")
  (d/create-database uri)
  (def conn (d/connect uri))
  (def mdb (db conn))
)

(defn create-partition []
  (d/transact conn [
    {:db/id (d/tempid :db.part/db)
     :db/ident :billing
     :db.install/_partition :db.part/db}
]))

(defn partitions []
  (d/q '[:find ?ident 
     :where 
     [:db.part/db :db.install/partition ?p]
     [?p :db/ident ?ident]
   ] mdb))

=> (create-mdb)
#'ww.billing/mdb
=> (create-partition)
#<promise$settable_future$reify__4637@714cf72c: {:db-before datomic.db.Db@193e901b, :db-after datomic.db.Db@eeb64b5b, :tx-data #<ArrayList [datomic.db.Datum@a15d2d7d, datomic.db.Datum@9f207ac0, datomic.db.Datum@7e4]>, :tempids {-9223367638809264704 62}}>
=> (partitions)
#<HashSet [[:db.part/db]]>
```

Any clue, please?

Answer (score 2):

In the query you are referencing an old database-value, from before you called **create-partition**.  Thus you do not see the changes you made to the database.

As a matter of fact you are being bitten by one of the most useful and distinguishing features of Datomic: the ability to "time-travel".

If you want to see the latest data in the database, you should obtain a new database-value before querying, eg. instead of **mdb** in the function **partitions**, you should write **(db conn)**.

Btw, in general you are asking for problems for yourself if you routinely use **def** inside functions, as **def** is meant for declarations, not general assignment.